# Calling/Choosing a Random Function with PHP

Tags: php, function

I have two functions that parse data and store a random item in an array. Now I want to implement logic that chooses one of these functions at random when executed via PHP. How can I achieve this?

My functions:

```
ReadQuote($csvFile, $arrayForStorage);
GetRandomURL($pageURL, $arrayForStorage);
```

I don't think the code is necessary for each of these functions, but if it is needed I will display it. Pretty lengthy though.

Comment: So you want to randomly call either `ReadQuote` or `GetRandomURL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
if (mt_rand(0, 100) < 50)
  ReadQuote($csvFile, $arrayForStorage);
else
  GetRandomURL($pageURL, $arrayForStorage);
```

Comment: Why 0-100? Why not `if (mt_rand(0, 1))`